# How to write "||" condition in Risc-V?

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

For example, in C

```
if (a == 0 || a == b) return 0;
```

I don't know exactly how to write multiple conditions in Risc-v. Could you guys help me figure it out?

Comment: Do you want with or without [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)? And what have you tried? Have you tried looking at code generated by a C compiler?

Comment: That's would be awesome if you can demonstrate both solutions for me, I've not tried one could you please suggest to me one also. I'm very very new in Risc-v and by the way thanks for the link you provided.

Comment: To skip the short-circuit evaluation (force to evaluate both expressions) you can use `if ((a == 0) + (a == b)) return 0;`, also take a look to https://godbolt.org/ , you can see the assembly output on several architectures

Comment: Just to be sure, we don't have a C to Risc-V compiler right now?

Comment: Draw a flowchart then code it up in asm. Or write it in C with simple `if` and `goto` (no `||`).

Comment: @Jester Thanks man, I think I got the idea

Answer (score 3):

It's broader than RISC V — all assembly languages use if-goto as their only conditional.

If-goto is used in `if`-then-`else` statements, `for`, `while`, and `do` and `repeat` loops, as well as for `&&` and `||` evaluation.

The operands to `||` can be separated and worked individually.

```
if ( a == 0 || a == b ) return 0;
```

can be translated into the if-goto form as follows:

```
    if ( a == 0 ) goto L1;      // fall thru only if a!=0
    if ( a != b ) goto L2;      // fall thru only if a==b, branch if a!=b
L1:
    return 0;                   // reaches here if either a==0 or else a==b
L2:                             // comes here if either a!=0 or else a!=b
```

---

For conjunction,

```
if ( a == 0 && b == 0 ) return 0;
```

can be translated into if-goto form as follows:

```
    if ( a != 0 ) goto L1;     // fall thru only if a==0, branch if a!=0
    if ( b != 0 ) goto L1;     // fall thru only if b==0, branch if b!=0
    return 0;                  // reaches here when both a==0 and b==0
L1:                            // comes here if either a!=0 or else b!=0
```

---

(There are, of course, other possible transformations.)

---

These translations into if-goto can be written rather directly in various assembly languages, using compare and branch.

In RISC V, the above if-goto translations can use branch equal (`beq`) or branch not equal (`bne`) instruction with two operands and a label.

For instruction sets that use condition codes, we write two instructions, a compare of the two operands, followed by a conditional branch to label on equal or not equal as appropriate.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's sometimes better to turn a condition into a boolean 0/1 in a register so you can AND multiple conditions together and branch once.  For example, `sltu r0, r1, 1` will be `1` only if r1 == 0.  (zero is the only number that's unsigned less-than 1.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, good point.  To emphasize in higher level terms, we can substitute`|`, `&` (logical or, and) for `||`, `&&` (short circuit or, and), respectively, for example, for conditions that don't require the short-circuit evaluation, and, for certain constructs on modern processors that would more efficient.

Comment: Just fyi, `ARM` doesn't always use if-goto, it has *conditional execution* on all of its instructions to avoid branching in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear: RISC-V already has several available C compilers (examples include GCC, LLVM and IAR), so you can take your existing C code and compile it for RISC-V just as for other targets like ARM.

If your question is really more about how to write something like that in RISC-V assembly, something like this could work (assuming a is in reg `a0` and b is in `a1`):

```
  beqz a0, is_true;    # Jump to the is_true label if a == 0
  beq a0, a1, is_true; # Jump to the is_true label if a == b
  j is_false;          # Jump to the is_false label to continue the function
is_true:
  mv a0, x0;           # Load 0 into the return value register (x0 is hard-wired 0)
  ret;
is_false:
  # Continue the function...
```